# Erro ao ler um arquivo txt python e somar a variável

Tags: python, if, pyautogui

Estou com um problema em uma automatização que utilizo.
Uso um TXT com algumas informações porem no IF não 'reconhece' a variável que adicionei no TXT.

```
import sys
import webbrowser
import random
import time
import pyautogui
import itertools
import pyperclip
    
uso3 = 's'
uso1 = "im"
    
with open("uso.txt") as file10:
    for (line10) in (file10):
             
        time.sleep(1)
        linha10 = line10
        
        webbrowser.open(site)
        time.sleep(10)

        # Adicionar Estoque
        print(type(linha10))
        print(type(uso1))
                    
        uso2 = linha10 + uso1
        
        print(uso2)
        
        if uso2 == "sim":
            print('teste.')
            
        else:
            print("merda")
            pyautogui.moveTo(602, 569, duration=0.30)
            pyautogui.click(602, 569, button='left', duration=0.25)
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.moveTo(642, 609, duration=0.30)
            pyautogui.click(642, 609, button='left', duration=0.25)
```

Comment: Onde que você declara `uso2` ?

Answer (score -1):

amigo,bem vindo a comunidade, experimenta usar esse codigo;
a variavel não esta reconhecendo porque a variavel não possui o valor "sim" que você botou no if;

```
import sys
import webbrowser
import random
import time
import pyautogui
import itertools
import pyperclip
    
uso3 = 's'
uso1 = "im"

site = "https://google.com"
    
with open("uso.txt") as file10: # le o arquivo e passa para a variavel file 10
    for line10 in file10: # pega o arquivo e passa todas as linhas para a variavel line10
             
        time.sleep(1) # espera 1 sec
        linha10 = line10 # passa line 10 para linha19

        
        webbrowser.open(site) # abre um site
        time.sleep(10) # espera

        #Adicionar Estoque 
        print(type(linha10)) # printa o tipo de variavel
        print(type(uso1)) # printa o tipo de variavel
                    
        uso2 = linha10 + uso1 # pega a variavel linha 10 adiciona mas o conteudo da variavel uso1 "im"
        
        print(uso2) # mostra  variavel
        
        if uso2 == "sim": # verifica se a variavel é igual a sim
            print('encontrado um sim no uso2')
        if uso2 == "merda":
            print("encontrado uma merda no uso2")

        else: # se não for da retorno a não
            print("merda")
            print("não foi  encontrado nada no uso2")
            pyautogui.moveTo(602, 569, duration=0.30) # move o mouse para o centro abaixo da tela
```

Comment: se você quer pegar a variavel "uso3" use:
uso2 =  str(uso3)+''+str(uso1))